# Code First, MVC drop down Categories & Subcategories

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

Client wants to add a product. When choosing Category, those available are not what this product falls under.

How do I have the category & subcategory drop downs include an option  among the other items so the client can add new categories/subcategories.

This just goes to show how little documentation is available out there. How ambiguous was my question.

I hate the fact that I have to form a relationship between product & category. EF fails in this regard.

My question is straight forward.

The client wants to add a product, the category drop down does not contain the category for this product. How can I  allow the client to add a category while adding the product?

Comment: This is a big question.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: please provide your working code. that will help us to answer you fast.

Comment: A starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259795/how-do-i-modelbind-a-many-to-many-relationship-with-mvc-3-and-entity-framework-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rick thank you very much, your links were an added value.

I figured out the answer to the problem where I do not want to form a true relationship between two classes and would like to share with others because there seems all too often only SIMPLIFIED examples to things.

If you have two classes where you want one to have a foreign key to the other but you do not want a true relationship with the later class to which the former has a foreign key to, eg Products & categories, here is what you do:

(1) Product 
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

(2)Category:
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List< Product > Products { get; set; }

And, there is NO fluent API for the above relationship!

By virtue of Category having a list of products and not a collection, no data relative to product is stored in the categories table.

Ricks link helps me figure out how a drop down values are dependent on the selection of a prior drop down, but I still have one more problem:

---

How to use jquery to dynamically post new value to drop down:

---

I followed this link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IRoe_ss_s5M
and indeed it does work when my view is called Sample8.

But my view is called _CreateOrEdit and there seems to be a conflict with that scenario. Any advice?

Comment: Edit your question for more details about your question or create a new one if you have follow-up questions. This answer section is a bad place (and only made for real answers) and nobody will recognize it as open question. After editing your question delete this answer here.

Answer (score -1):

```
 public class ProductTable
     {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string CategoryName{get;set;}

        public virtual Category Categories { get; set; }
      }

       public class CategoryTable
        {
           public int CategoryId { get; set; }
           public string Name { get; set; }
           public static ICollection<ProductTable> Products{get;set;}
        }
```